# Spring application.yaml and boolean values through env file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, properties, environment-variables

In my Spring Boot project, I have to pass to application.yaml file the SHOW_SQL boolean value from an environment file.

Here is application.yaml

```
spring:
  ... 
  show-sql: ${SHOW_SQL}
  ...

server:
  port: 8080
```

Here is my env file (used to start the spring app)

```
SHOW_SQL=true
```

During the **mvn test** process I receive this error

```
Failed to bind properties under 'spring.jpa.show-sql' to boolean:
    Property: spring.jpa.show-sql
    Value: "${SHOW_SQL}"
    Origin: class path resource [application.yaml] - 13:15
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to boolean (caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value '${SHOW_SQL}')
Action:
Update your application's configuration
```

Is there a way to use boolean values from an .env file and pass them to the application yaml?

Comment: For testing you could have a separate `application.yaml` in your `src/test/resources` directory

Comment: This part `Value: "${SHOW_SQL}"` of the error message looks to me like suggesting `SHOW_SQL` isn't set because I would expect its value there. Are you sure the variable is set and available to your application?

Comment: Yes, this value is set in env file. However, I fixed this error creating a new application.yaml under test folder as suggested.